# Cakephp : Getting error on sending mail to customer while checkout

Tags: php, cakephp, smtp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on online shopping project.My project works good in my localhost i can checkout and able to receive mail but when i tried to checkout on live server i am getting error :`Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`i am using CakePHP 2.7

**This is my function to send mail**

```
public function send_mail($address,$subject,$body)
{
        App::import('Vendor', 'mail_class/PHPMailer');
        $username="viky.031290@gmail.com";
        $password="XXXXXXXX";


        $mail             = new PHPMailer();




        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                                               // 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = $username; // SMTP account username
        $mail->Password   = $password;        // SMTP account password

        $mail->SetFrom($username, 'Orangemart');



        $mail->Subject    = $subject;



        $mail->MsgHTML($body);


        $mail->AddAddress($address, "");

        //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
        //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
             echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    }
```

**This is my checkout function**

```
public function checkout()
{
    $this->layout="checkout";

    $this->loadModel("Cart");
    $cartcount = $this->Cart->find('count',array(
                                            'conditions' => array('public_id' => $this->Session->read("id"))
                                        )
                                );
    $this->set('count', $cartcount);

    if(isset($_REQUEST["checkout"]))
    {
        $this->loadModel("Ordermaster");
        $this->loadModel("Cart");
        $this->loadModel("Orderdetail");
        $this->request->data["date"] = date('y-m-d');
        $this->request->data["publics_tbls_id"] = $this->Session->read("id");

        $return=$this->Ordermaster->save($this->request->data);
        //print_r($return);
        $this->Session->write("orderid",$return["Ordermaster"]["id"]);

        $dt=$this->Cart->find("all",array("conditions"=>array("public_id"=>$this->Session->read("id"))));

        $str="<div class='top' style='height:100px;width:500px;background-color:Orange;color:white'><center><h1 style='padding:25px;font-size:50px';>OrangeMart</h1></center></div>";

        $str.="<h3>Detail Order</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Date:</b>".$return["Ordermaster"]["date"]."</li>
        <li><b>Order ID:</b>".$return["Ordermaster"]["id"]."</li>
    </ul>";
            $str.="<table border='2'>";
                    $str.="<tr height='50px'>
                                <td align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Product Name</b></font></td>
                                <td align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Qty</b></font></td>
                                <td align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Price</b></font></td>
                            </tr>";
        $subtotal=0;
        foreach($dt as $row)
        {
                $this->request->data["ordermaster_id"]=$return["Ordermaster"]["id"];
                $this->request->data["product_tbls_id"]=$row["Cart"]["product_tbls_id"];
                $this->request->data["qty"]=$row["Cart"]["qty"];
                $this->request->data["psize"]=$row["Cart"]["psize"];
                $this->request->data["price"]=$row["product_tbls"]["price"];

                $this->Orderdetail->create();
                $this->Orderdetail->save($this->request->data);


                    $str.="<tr height='50px'>";
                            $str.=" <td align='center'>".$row["product_tbls"]["name"].(($row["Cart"]["psize"]!==Null)?' (Size '.$row["Cart"]["psize"].')':"")./*" (Size ".$row["Cart"]["psize"].")".*/"</td>
                                <td align='center'>".$row["Cart"]["qty"]."</td>
                                <td align='center'> Rs. ".$row["Cart"]["price"]."</td>";
                    $str.="</tr>";
            $subtotal=$subtotal+$row["Cart"]["price"];
        }
        $str.="<tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>SubTotal</b></td><td align='center'><b>".' Rs. '.$subtotal."</b></font></td></tr>
            <tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Payment Method</b></td><td align='center'><b>"."Cash on Delevery"."</b></font></td></tr>";

        if($subtotal>2000)
        {
            $str.="<tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Shipping Cost</b></td><td align='center'><b>FREE</b></font></td></tr>";
            $str.="<tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Total</b></td><td align='center'><b> Rs. ".$subtotal."</b></font></td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            $str.="<tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Shipping Cost</b></td><td align='center'><b> Rs. 99</b></font></td></tr>";
            $str.="<tr height='50px'><td colspan='2' align='center' bgcolor='black'><font color='white'><b>Total</b></td><td align='center'><b> Rs. ".($subtotal+99)."</b></font></td></tr>";
        }

        $str.="</table>";

        $str.="</br><ul>
                        <li><b>Note:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["note"]."</li>
                    </ul>";

        $str.="<h3>Customer details</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Name:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["name"]."</li>
                <li><b>Email:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["email"]."</li>
                <li><b>Contact No:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["contact"]."</li>
                <li><b>Address:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["address"]."</li>
                <li><b>Pincode:</b> ".$return["Ordermaster"]["pincode"]."</li>
            </ul>";

        $this->send_mail($this->request->data["email"],"OrangeMart",$str);
        $this->send_mail("viky.031290@gmail.com","New Order",$str);

        $this->Cart->query("delete from cart_tbls where public_id=".$this->Session->read("id"));
        $this->redirect("../public/thankyou");
            //$this->Session->setFlash(__('My message.'), 'flash_notification');
            //$this->Session->setFlash('Successully added to cart!');

    }

    $this->loadModel("Addcat");
    $data = $this->Addcat->find('all');
    $this->set('cat', $data);

    $this->loadModel("Subcat");
    $data = $this->Subcat->query('select * from subcategory_tbls where sub_cat IN ("jeans","T-shirt","dresses","top")');
    $this->set('product1', $data);

}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with your code. do you use shared hosting or you vps or some dedicated server?

Comment: @pregmatch yes i am using shared hosting

Comment: i solved my problem by contacting my hosting provider

Comment: @pregmatch: there is no harm in using tags to indicate what technologies are being used. Watchers of the PHP tag would be able to suggest fixes for this, so it doesn't seem correct to me to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: OP: we don't used [solved] in the title here. You can either self-answer the question using the answer box, or request that the question is closed as 'unable to reproduce'. The latter feels appropriate in this case.